# Process XML with inline groovy script

Tags: xml, groovy

I would like to prepare sample XML files with dynamic content. I am interesting in  a way to put a groovy code (or any other script language) inside XML file and to process it to get a XML file populated with values that results inline scripts.

for example:

```
<myXmldata>
     <node>testSample ${=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())}</node>
</myXmldata>
```

and after the file would be processed i would get:

```
<myXmldata>
  <node>testSample 20150326140122</node>
</myXmldata>`
```

I saw something similar in SoapUI and in maven scripts, but i do not know how to "execute" such a file.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simplest case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

println(
"""
<myXmldata>
     <node>testSample ${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(new Date())}</node>
</myXmldata>
"""
)
```

Have a look at [templates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html) - it might be what you are looking for.